# Jenkins Performance trend report export

Tags: performance, jenkins, jmeter

I want to export the performance trend report from Jenkins and share it using HTML format. Is there any way to export the performance trend report from Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

You can use export plugin like this one: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Export+Report
 or you can locate the json or xml file that gets generated and write your own script to publish in HTML format.